# Order by column is sorting String like though it is an Integer column

Tags: qgis, table, sorting

The question is very easy. The usual sorting of an Integer column is really bad. I need it like 1,2,3...11,12 and so on. But currently it's more like 1,10,11...2,20...

Here a picture
[image]

Is there an easy way to change that? I mean without making the 1 going "01" or such tricks would be the best.

### It is not a String column

Here it is not working.
[image]
Here it's working.
[image]

In both cases **int**.

Comment: Is it possible that your id field is a string?

Comment: Nop, already checked it. But the strange thing is that I have another shape file. With also id that is an integer and there it works properply and is sorted in the right way. =(

Comment: It is odd, yet I suggest that you try to create a new ID field as an integer, it might work. What is the width of the current ID field?

Comment: I suggest you edit the fact that the field is an integer into your question

Comment: Could you share a small bad behaving shapefile so others could test it with their own QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probable that your ID field is a string. You can veirfy it in the layer properties window under the fields tab. If so, create a new ID field which is an integer and feed it with the string-id values. see example:
[image: ID as a String]
and using an integer instead:
[image: Id as an Integer]

Comment: Added proof picture above that show that it is no a String issue. But I already had issues with columns. There the only solution was a complete new creation of them. I think this is just another bug of QGIS =/

Comment: It is indeed possible; as suggested in my last comment above, to apply the solution anyway, did opening a new field helped at all?

Comment: QGIS is really buggy somehow. I restarted PC and started QGIS and now it works as expected. I did not change anything. So again a bug in terms of that I must say anyway awesome tool.